# PowerApps Navigation From Excel File Data Source

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am using a simple 2-column Excel file as the data source for a gallery inserted on every screen for a navigation bar.  The columns are "Name" (to be displayed on nav bar buttons as text) and "TableRef" (will be used in Navigate() function for name of screen to display).  The text on the buttons is working, displaying the contents of the Excel file column "Name" on each one.

I am setting the Text for each button to "ThisItem.Name" and it is working. However, I cannot use "Navigate(ThisItem.TableRef, Fade)" for the button's OnSelect.

What am I missing?  Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I need to use Lookup() within the Navigate function, but I can't get it to work.  The Excel table name in this PowerApp is "Table1". The gallery name is "Gallery_Navigation".

Navigate(LookUp(Table1, TableRef = Gallery_Navigation.Selected.TableRef), ScreenTransition.Fade)

But the above code does not work. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set the item property of the other gallery you are navigating to as The first galleryname you are navigating from .selected. For example, if the gallery name you want to navigate from is Gallery1 and the one you are navigating to is Gallery2, then on the item property of Gallery2, type 
`Gallery1.Seleted` Then on Gallery1 just make the Onselect Poreperty fro Navigating Navigate(Gallery2, ScreenTransition.Fade)
Let me know if this work or you stil have any other issues.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Akande for your response. Since this is a gallery, I cannot click on multiple buttons to access their individual properties. As a result, they all have to be set via the one button.

I have tried this but it will not retrieve the URL contained in the Excel file's TableRef column. Any recommendations?

Navigate(LookUp(Table1, TableRef = Gallery_Navigation.Selected.TableRef), ScreenTransition.Fade)